# Java - how to select by attribute value that contains new line

Tags: java, xpath, newline

How to deal with new line characters in XPath queries?

The following fails:

```
public class XPathWithNewLine {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xml = "<root text=\"hi\nho\"> </root>";
        String xpathStr = "//*[@text='hi\nho']";

        NodeList list = eval(xml, xpathStr);
        if (list != null && list.getLength() > 0) {
            System.out.println(list.item(0).getNodeName());
        } else {
            System.err.println("Failed!");
        }
    }

    public static NodeList eval(String xml, String xpathStr) {
        XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));

        NodeList nodeList = null;
        try {
            nodeList = (NodeList) xpath.compile(xpathStr).evaluate(source, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return nodeList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike element content, attribute values are [normalized](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#AVNormalize).  Any sequence of whitespace characters (including '\n') is converted to a single ASCII space for the purpose of any XML processing.  So, effectively, your XML is really:

```
String xml = "<root text=\"hi ho\"> </root>";
```

On the other hand, character entities are not normalized.  So if you change that line to this, the program should work:

```
String xml = "<root text=\"hi&#xa;ho\"> </root>";
```

Comment: Thanks, `String xml = "<root text=\"hi&#xa;ho\"> </root>"; String xpathStr = "//*[@text='hi\nho']";` Actually works. My problem was I thought the xpath query also gets normelized and tried `"//*[@text='hi&#xa;ho']";`...